# KnockoutJS - Recalculate computed values with a set time interval

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this code here

```
self.timestamp = ko.observable(data.timestamp);
self.dateFromNow = ko.computed(function ()
{
    return moment(self.timestamp()).fromNow();
}, self);
```

`self.timestamp` is simply a unix timestamp

`self.dateFromNow` looks something like `44 years ago` or `1 minute ago`

My goal is for `self.dateFromNow` to recompute every set time interval.

These properties are bound to HTML `<time>` elements but I don't want to do the recomputation by using JS/jQuery to go over the elements and recompute.
I think a better way would be just to simply recalculate the values in KnockoutJS every set time interval and let KO update the markup.

Is there a way to do this in KnockoutJS?

**UPDATE**: What I did was something like this in lieu of the poster's answer

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.each(self.foo(), function(index, item) {
    item.timestamp.notifySubscribers();
  });
}, 60 * 1000); // 60 * 1000 milsec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not built into knockout, no (at least, not as far as I know). It has a mechanism (throttling) that limits how often view model changes are propagated through, but obviously that's not what you're after. Arguably you should have a member on your view model that you bind through to your element, and then it's your responsibility to update your view model periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the response Matt. I could theoretically just loop over the bound elements and force them to recompute. I was just hoping that there might be a way for KO to do it, via extenders or custom bindings.

Comment: You're welcome. Why deal with the DOM elements to force an update, though? The beauty of MVVM is that you can abstract the behaviour of values from their display. If you make the VM responsible for updating its value, your update behaviour will be preserved irrespective of whether it's bound to a label, input, etc.

Comment: Exactly why I don't want to deal with DOM elements. What I did is as you suggested, putting a setInterval function to the Models to update the properties periodically.

`setInterval(function() {
 $.each(self.foo(), function(index, item) {
      item.timestamp.notifySubscribers();
 });
}, 60 * 1000); // 60 * 1000 milsec`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to handle this would be to re-evaluate the computeds whenever another observable changes value, which changes on an interval.  Sound crazy?

```
var fireEvaluations = ko.observable(0);

// Somewhere after the DOM is ready
setInterval(function () {
    fireEvaluations(fireEvaluations() + 1);
}, 6000);

var someOtherObservable = ko.computed(function () {
    // Subscribe to the triggering observable
    if (fireEvaluations()) { }
    // Do your real code
});
```

Now all computeds which have something like if (fireEvaluations()) { } will re-evaluate once that value changes.

Comment: Thanks for response. That could also work but I figured that it would be easier to just use `notifySubscribers()`